# What is going on with the lslogins instruction

Tags: command-line, batch, hacking

The `lslogins` instructions lists down the user info of all users however isnt this unsafe?

For example suppose a hacker pretends to like you and ends up spending the night with you just to access your computer physically , she could have written a `.sh` file before which uses the data given out by the `lslogins` instruction and logs in your computer and injects 'sleeper agent' files which would transfer your data(credit card number and pwd) to her if some condition is met.

So what is the catch here?

Comment: If a "hacker" were to get to your computer physically, then `lslogins` is the least of your problems ... Login names are not a big issue anyways as authentication and permissions are still required for other users (other than your currently logged in user) ... Take a look at `cat /etc/passwd`, login names are there as well.

Comment: If your data is so valuable to others as to be worth seducing you to gain access, then encryption, backups, secure physical storage, and other protections may be required by your employer. Also, um, stop picking up and bringing sexual partners and other unknown folks to any location with valuables. That's just poor judgement.

Comment: Your data may not be valuable hackers target normal people most of the time(a lot of them).The hacker doesnt know if you have enough savings in your bank account but the fact that she doesnt know makes you a valid target.

Comment: So if u have enough money then she will get paid well , else uhm unlucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The lslogins instructions lists down the user info of all users however isnt this unsafe?

No,it is not.

As with all things related to operating systems: physical access means that person owns the machine. That user could reboot the system, and use an USB live session to mount the disks and be "root". Not even a boot password will stop someone. Formatting a disk is pretty easy to do too.

There is nothing to 'secure' here. Any security measure is also going the hinder the actual owner of the machine if that person forgets a needed password.

> and logs in your computer

Without knowing the password to enter the desktop or command line? How do you see that happening?

Comment: "Without knowing the password to enter the desktop or command line? How do you see that happening?".Well you can open the terminal before you log in the desktop.

Comment: still need a password

Answer (score 0):

If a 'hacker' has physical access to your login-account (that is she by "social engineering" has got your password, or you have left the account logged in) those information, and many others, is available anyway by other commands. `cat /etc/passwd` gives the same and more.

Comment: @mook765...yes, off-course ;-) I have edited the answer.